# Использование unset для пагинатора

Tags: php

```
foreach ($arResult['matches'] as $keyids):
    if ($countpagesID < $pagefrom and $countpagesID > $pageto):
        unset($arResult['matches'][$keyids]);
        $arResult['other'][] = $keyids;
    endif;
    $countpagesID++;
endforeach;
```

- $pagefrom - с какого элемента показывать например, для второй страницы будет 10
- $pageto - по какой элемент показывать, для второй страницы будет 20

Но данный код не срабатывает. Может кто подскажет, что не так?

```
[matches] => Array
        (
            [34888] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 34888
                )

            [14095] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 14095
                )

            [10949] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 10949
                )

            [26050] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 26050
                )

            [7116] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 7116
                )

            [11601] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 11601
                )

            [17965] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 17965
                )

            [23928] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 23928
                )

            [10082] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 10082
                )

            [9177] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 9177
                )

            [9242] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 9242
                )

            [32713] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 32713
                )

            [7096] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 7096
                )

            [33016] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 33016
                )

            [32755] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 32755
                )

            [31880] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 31880
                )

            [32754] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 32754
                )

            [40590] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 40590
                )

            [23516] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 23516
                )

            [13222] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 13222
                )

            [31268] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 31268
                )

            [40617] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 40617
                )

            [31445] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 31445
                )

            [16106] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 16106
                )

            [39461] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 39461
                )

            [37780] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 37780
                )

            [8425] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 8425
                )

            [35083] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 35083
                )

            [32753] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 32753
                )

            [34227] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 34227
                )

            [32751] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 32751
                )

            [34224] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 34224
                )

            [38944] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 38944
                )

            [35469] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 35469
                )

            [14703] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 14703
                )

            [12851] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 12851
                )

            [12068] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 12068
                )

            [7874] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 7874
                )

            [12270] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 12270
                )

            [7347] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 7347
                )

            [17299] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 17299
                )

            [15794] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 15794
                )

            [8880] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 8880
                )

            [12846] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 12846
                )

            [9422] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 9422
                )

            [9031] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 9031
                )

            [9816] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 9816
                )

            [11875] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 11875
                )

            [16573] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 16573
                )

            [13891] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 13891
                )

            [28110] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 28110
                )

            [28003] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 28003
                )

            [23922] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 23922
                )

            [9716] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 9716
                )

            [25608] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 25608
                )

            [28108] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 28108
                )

        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
array_slice($arResult['matches'],$pagefrom,($pageto-$pagefrom));
```

А вообще, нужен vardump массива. Может, вы не оттуда пытаетесь извлекать.

```
print_r(array_slice($a['matches'],0,10,true));
print_r(array_slice($a['matches'],10,10,true));
print_r(array_slice($a['matches'],20,10,true));
print_r(array_slice($a['matches'],30,10,true));
```

Comment: Оттуда, добавил массив к вопросу. array_slice не помог когда пошли дальше первой страницы

Comment: Прошу прощения. Ча поправлю.

Comment: Да, вы правы :)не правильно только было написано array_slice($arResult['matches'],$pagefrom,($pageto-$pagefrom));, надо array_slice($arResult['matches'],$pagefrom,10,true);

Comment: Ну если у вас $pageto-$pagefrom равно 10, то да.